# Accessing object in RunningObjectTable (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, createinstance

I've two applications. The first application registers an object with a ProgID in the RunningObjectTable.. that works totally fine. The other application should access that object by the ProgID.

I found three possible ways to do so.. but just one works and I wonder why.. what are the differences between these ways?

First: [IRunningObjectTable.GetObject(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683841(v=vs.85).aspx) => not working

```
IRunningObjectTable rot;
GetRunningObjectTable(0, out rot); // => ole32.dll
IMoniker moniker;
CreateFileMoniker("myProgId", out moniker); // => ole32.dll
object myObj;
rot.GetObject(moniker, out myObj) // => myObj stays null
```

Second: [Marshal.GetActiveObject(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/office/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject(v=vs.71)) => not working

```
object myObj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("myProgId"); // => throws an exception: MK_E_UNAVAILABLE
```

Third: [Activator.CreateInstance(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) => works

```
object myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("myProgId"), true);
```

Comment: The 3rd way does not use the ROT at all, it creates a new instance.  If you are not paying attention to the error or exception returned by GetObject() then you can't know why "it does not work".  Roman made a pretty good substitute available for the irotview utility: http://alax.info/blog/1444

Answer (score -1):

Available content of the ROT depends on the user permissions. Most probably you are starting your applications with different user permissions, or one of the apps was started in "run as administrator" mode

Use next code to get the content of ROT, and compare content in both applications.

```
IRunningObjectTable rot;
GetRunningObjectTable(0, out rot);

IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator;
rot.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);

IntPtr pNumFetched = new IntPtr();
IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];

while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, pNumFetched) == 0)
{
    IBindCtx bindCtx;
    CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);
    string displayName;
    monikers[0].GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out displayName);
    // Console.WriteLine(displayName);
}
```